# How I ask to user to rate the app and share it on facebook

Tags: android, google-play

I'm in the final stages of a project (my first project), but I'm stumbling in some points yet.

Like:

- I want to ask the user to rate the app and also share it on facebook, but not only this, after I need also check if he/she really did this, and how many stars he/she rated the app. 
  I found this answer to ask the user to rate the app:

/* inside an activity */

```
final Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
final Intent rateAppIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);

if (getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(rateAppIntent, 0).size() > 0)
{
    startActivity(rateAppIntent);
}
else
{
    /* handle your error case: the device has no way to handle market urls */
}
```

Seems to me a easy way, but how my app wasn't published yet, I have no way to test... And I don't know how it works (and if it works), this show a kind of native dialog? Anyone already did this way? And how I can check if a user really rated the app and how many stars the user gave programmatically? I need this answer to run a code.

- And to share I can use a intent, ok, but and then, how I check if the user really shared it?

Any tip or link to any example will be very welcome.

Comment: You can always test it with an arbitrary already published app, no need for it to be your own

Comment: @Kiskae How? Like I said it is my first app... Can you give a link or a example... Thanks

Comment: Instead of using `getApplicationContext().getPackageName()`, just grab a publically listed package id like `com.whatsapp` and see what happens when you run the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly as far as I know.. It's not possible to check if user have rated your app or not. You can google that to know the reasons. Best approach is to count launches of app by user ( ideally #5 ) then show dialog asking user rate app. You can use this tool https://github.com/delight-im/AppRater

Regarding sharing .. its similar.. Normally it should not be allowed. My favorite approach is to track user posting by injecting user data (hashed) to a link inside the post content and track clicking. You may shorten link. There are many tools to do so such as Bit.ly, use this lib to achieve that on android https://github.com/dextorer/Bitlyzer

I hope that may help,'.

Comment: Thanks. This was very helpful.